# Notation of the differential operator

Tags: notation, differential-operators

I see the differential operator both with upright and italic d in different books/articles. So I'm curious about
$$ \int x^2 \, dx \quad \text{vs.} \quad \int x^2\, \mathrm{d}x,$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) \quad \text{vs.} \quad \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x).$$

Is there a convention which of these notations should be used?

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no difference between the two. Its difficult to write in italics by hand though-only in textbooks.

Comment: I only used $d$ because I didn't know about the other one. Having seen it - it's quite long, as in to type!

Comment: Yes, there is a convention. In fact, there are two :)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905332/notation-problem-in-integration-write-dx-or-mathrmdx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick answer: [there is a standard](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) to follow.

Longer answer: while physicists write differential operators in upright fonts (because they follow the standards), mathematicians tend to typeset differential operators as variables (because we are lazy). I am joking, but it should be clear that $dx$ is **not** $d \cdot x$, and that $d$ is essentially an operator: therefore it is always preferable to write $\mathrm{d}x$ instead. Many journals change $dx$ to $\mathrm{d}x$ after accepting a manuscript for publications.

Comment: Just to point out that this is by no means a universally accepted standard. (I give examples in my post below.)

Comment: It puzzles me that this standard seems to be accepted everywhere but pure mathematics. Imagine if a mathematician writing about quantum mechanics used $h$ in place of $\hbar$. S/he would be maligned, and rightly so.

Comment: By the logic of that example, the 'home' subject should set the standard. In which case, $d$ is looking better and better.

Comment: @SimonS No, $dx$ or $d\mu$ cannot be distinguished from the multiplication of two variables. This is why we use $\lim$ instead of $lim$, or $\sin \alpha$ instead of $sin\, \alpha$.

Comment: If we really thought we interpret without looking at context, I would be on your side. But to give an example from the OP: there is only one coherent interpretation of $$\int x^2 \ dx$$ and it doesn't involve the possibility that $d$ is a variable. The editors of some of the best mathematics journals of the world appear to agree.

Comment: @SimonS And that's why we have standards ;-) To avoid such discussions...

Comment: Fair enough. Let me try a perhaps clearer analogy: there is only one reasonable interpretation of "For a circle, $A = \prod r^2$." Do you find this acceptable typesetting? It is a precisely analogous error of confusing a variable with an operator.

Comment: I thought $dx$ was the variable, and therefore italic?

Answer (score 26):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but with regards to typesetting in $\LaTeX$, let me point out that typing `\mathrm{d}` should **not** take longer than typing `d`, as you **shouldn't be doing either throughout your paper**!

The semantically correct thing to do is to define a macro representing your desired differential operator, for example, `\newcommand{\dv}[1]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} #1}}`. Then, whenever you need to typeset $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$, you simply use `\dv{x}` or `\dv{t}`, which is even easier than the non-standards-conforming `\frac{d}{dx}`.

This has the added benefit that, should you find yourself submitting to a publisher whose house style requires italic $d$'s, you need only change the definition of your macro instead of modifying every differential operator by hand.

Answer (score 14):

Many excellent journals and books use $d$ in the italics form, such as the *Journal of the American Mathematical Society* (e.g., [recent article by Terence Tao](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/0000-000-00/S0894-0347-2015-00838-4/S0894-0347-2015-00838-4.pdf)), *London Mathematical Society Proceedings* (e.g., equations 74 and 75 of [this recent paper](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/111/1/63.full.pdf+html)) and Spivak's *Calculus*.

Given that reference quality publications use $d$--and that it is faster and cleaner to typeset it that way--the italics form is more than respectable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between them. It merely comes as a result of a choice in LaTeX formatting; specifically, some people write "\text{d}" (or some equivalent) for the upright formatting, but many other people don't do this for the sake of speed, and instead just write "d".

Comment: Writing `\text{d}` is not a good idea, as the shape and font used then depends on the shape and font surrounding the formula (if that's italic, the d will be italic as well). Use `\mathrm{d}`.

Answer (score 3):

In Germany, there is the DIN 1338 standard, according to which the differntial operator `d`, as, e.g., `e` for the Euler number, should be typeset as an upright letter.

According to Wikipedia, these letters are typeset in italic if AMS conventions are used.

Answer (score 1):

By logic I think that is a good idea differentiate the symbol with the roman notation but there isnt a "standard", you can use any of them.

In the same sense doesnt exist any kind of "standard" mathematical notation. I read a lot of books of many mathematical topics, everyone with different notations, not only just the infinitesimal symbol.

The problem, writing on LATEX, is that it take more time to write $\color{red}{\mathrm d}$ instead of just $\color{red}{d}$.

Comment: `\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}`

Answer (score 0):

The AMS Style Guide (October 2017) appears to use italics, ex. pages 102, 115, though interestingly there is an example of upright d on p. 32.

[In a discussion on Wikipedia from 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Mathematics/Archive/2005/Jan-Mar#straight_or_italic_d?), Toby Bartels brought up a possibility that it is a US/UK difference, though personally I haven't seen evidence of this.

Another wikipedia discussion with an anonymous answer that sampled a bunch of books and found different styles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Differential_(infinitesimal)#d_versus_d